# Why can't I start "Under New Management?"

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I finished "Blindsighted" for the Thieves Guild, and before doing "Darkness Returns" I powered through all of Vex and Delvin's side quests. I got all four merchants and special quests, however after completing the final special quest, "Under New Management" never showed up.

After that I finished "Darkness Returns" (and got the achievement), fast traveled to the Cistern, talked to Brynolf (he gave me his congratulatory spiel, even called me guild master), but still no "Under New Management" quest. Talking to Delvin or Vex only yields their standard dialogue for getting side jobs. I tried console-commanding the quest to start (I did `setstage tgleadership 0, 10, 40 and 200`) but all it says in the console is `getstage >> 10` and nothing changes.

I've checked the quest log and "Imitation Amnesty," "Silver Lining," "Summerset Shadows" and "The Dainty Sload" are all under the completed section. I have no running side Thieves Guild quests either.

How do I start "Under New Management?"

Comment: So, you have done all 4/5 side-quests from each city except for Riften and Raven Rock?

Comment: No mods, I assume? The [wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Under_New_Management) suggests, at the bottom, and certain mods may interfere with this, although that's totally unsubstantiated. Still it would be good to know if you've got anything running that may interfere.

Comment: Yea you need to do the 5 main thieves side-missions in the main cities.

Comment: i have a sizable amount of mods, but none that affect the thieves guild in any way. Also, it says in most places that you only have to do quests in 4 citys as riften already has a thievs guild presence.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Ragged Flagon a few times. Then Brynjolf will have the dialogue reset and you can go to the cistern and talk to the elf.